# How to convert contents saved from markdown back to html

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-mvc, markdown

I have rendered [simplemde-markdown-editor](http://nextstepwebs.github.io/simplemde-markdown-editor/) in jsp page as

```
<article class="post">
    <div class="form-style-2">      
        <form:form method="post" commandName="post">
            <form:input cssClass="input-field" path="postTitle"/>            
            <form:textarea id="editor" path="postBody"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Post"/>    
        </form:form>
    </div>
</article>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    new SimpleMDE({
        element: document.getElementById("editor"),
        spellChecker: false,
    });
</script>
```

all set perfectly working good, but when I browse saved contents of markdown I get same symbols as of

```
#### Unordered
* Lists are a piece of cake
* They even auto continue as you type
* A double enter will end them
* Tabs and shift-tabs work too
```

any help please.
Thanks

Comment: What does it mean "When I browse saved contents of markdown"?

Comment: I mean to say that when I save the contents from the `textarea` all the markdown stuff is saved in DB, Now I want to get the contents in the format of HTML not the markdown stuff as I've mentioned above.

Comment: I think you should save the Markdown in the database and render the HTML when the content is requested. Otherwise it will be difficult for users to edit their contents

Answer (score -1):

just use `simplemde.markup(simplemde.value());`